# iPhone Fingerprint sensor for passwords

Tags: ios, iphone, touch-id

Is there any way I could setup the fingerprint I'd to work in place of typing in my iCloud password whenever prompted, or perhaps even other passwords in keychain?

I had to upgrade to a 5s yesterday and as is the fingerprint id thing seems pretty useless if I can't set it up as a replacement for passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your device is jailbroken, you can install [**iTouchSecure**](http://www.itouchsecure.com/cydia/itouchsecure/) which lets you use the Touch ID feature for any password entry area in any app, including iCloud password dialogs.

> [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted.  I'm curious why Apple wouldn't build it for that purpose to begin with?